# How do I fix my code for insert into SQL Server with Python 3.7

Tags: python, pymssql

I try to insert data into a SQL Server table with Python37 (pymssql), but I get an error as shown below. Do you have any suggestion?

These are the values to be inserted into the table

```
values = ['test','test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test','test','test','test','test','test','test','test','test']
```

SQL string in python code

```
insSQL = '''INSERT INTO [dbo].[S_LAZ_GET_ORDERS](ORDER_ID,
                                                   ORDER_NUMBER,
                                                   BILL_ADDRESS1,
                                                   BILL_ADDRESS2,
                                                   BILL_ADDRESS3,
                                                   BILL_ADDRESS4,
                                                   BILL_ADDRESS5,
                                                   BILL_CITY,
                                                   BILL_COUNTRY,
                                                   BILL_FIRST_NAME,
                                                   BILL_LAST_NAME,
                                                   BILL_PHONE,
                                                   BILL_PHONE2,
                                                   BILL_POST_CODE)
              VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)''' 

  cur.executemany(insSQL, values)
  cur.commit()
```

This is the error I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "src_mssql.pyx", line 1930, in _mssql._substitute_params
> IndexError: tuple index out of range
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "D:\Python Project\Lazada API\getOrder.py", line 125, in  getorders()
> File "D:\Python Project\Lazada API\getOrder.py", line 109, in getorders
> cur.executemany(insSQL, values)
>
> File "src\pymssql.pyx", line 476, in pymssql.Cursor.executemany
> File "src\pymssql.pyx", line 450, in pymssql.Cursor.execute
> File "src_mssql.pyx", line 1070, in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.execute_query
> File "src_mssql.pyx", line 1101, in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.execute_query
> File "src_mssql.pyx", line 1218, in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.format_and_run_query
> File "src_mssql.pyx", line 1240, in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.format_sql_command
> File "src_mssql.pyx", line 1932, in _mssql._substitute_params
>
> ValueError: more placeholders in SQL than params available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list `values` should be a sequence of parameters (each element inside `values` is a single row to be inserted). So if you want to insert one row into your table where each cell in the row has the value 'test' then simply put one 14-element tuple inside values as follows:

```
values = [('test','test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test','test','test','test','test','test','test','test','test')]
```

If you want to add more rows, simply add more tuples to `values`.